# Cakephp - Popup to confirm existing entry

Tags: cakephp, popup, submit, confirm

From my template, when I click on submit, I have to check if one of the fields of my form exist in another table yet and if it's, show  popup with OK/Cancel
How can I do that?

Comment: It would be great to see some code, that way people can understand your problem better.

Comment: You can do it with Ajax. There's lots of information out there about using Ajax with Cake.